# Update with rsync, copy newer files but skip unmodified files with different GID

Tags: rsync, gid

I have Manjaro linux on desktop and laptop. Both have the same username with UID=1000, but GID differs. GID=1000 on desktop and 1001 on laptop. Most of files are same on both machines. Sometimes I work on one, other times on another machine. I sync the files with rsync. The problem is that following rsync command copies even those files which exist on destination, just because GIDs differ:

`rsync -vazu user@desktop:~/Documents/* ./`

I want to update newer files (the ones which have been modified) but not to copy the files with same modification date (i.e. unchanged files) and different GID. What is the rsync option to achieve this?

Comment: Is the `--groupmap` option what you're looking for? It will map the gid's between systems. I have not checked if it still tries to transfer files. Use `--dry-run` to see if this works for you.

Comment: Try with the option `--no-group`